# page loading time of a cached page

Tags: plugins, performance

I am trying to find page loading time of a page using following code

```
function loading_time() {


 echo '<p>Page loading time:'.timer_stop(0, 3).' seconds</p>';

}

 add_action( 'shutdown', 'loading_time' );
```

The code works perfectly for non cached pages but for cached pages the shutdown hook never fires.Is there any way to find out the page loading time of cached pages without firing the wordpress hook?

Comment: Cached how exactly? Does your caching plugin cache the whole page or just part of it? If it's the whole page then you might not have anywhere to hook into - it depends on the plugin and the mechanism used.

Comment: yes the whole page is cached.is there any way to achieve my goal without firing the hook ?

Comment: OK. How is the cached page served? By some code in a plugin? You can hook into that. By your web server directly without going through WordPress? You might have to get statistics from the web server instead.

Comment: The cached page is served by a caching plugin.I am trying to access the loading time from a plugin so server statistics is not going to help.

Comment: OK, so you'll have to look at whichever caching plugin it is and work out how you can get whatever statistics you want from that.

Comment: i am trying to make the plugin compatible for all caching plugin not for a particular one so your suggestion not going to help !